# Check whether the mentioned member is not author and offline and a bot

Tags: discord.py

I have made a discord bot in which there is a rob command as follow:-

```py
@client.command(aliases=['rb'])
@commands.cooldown(2, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
async def rob(ctx,member : discord.Member):
  if not member == ctx.author and discord.Status.offline and member.bot:
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    await open_account(member)
    bal = await update_bank(member)


    if bal[0]<100:
        await ctx.send('It is useless to rob them :(')
        return

    earning = random.randrange(0,bal[0])
    

    await update_bank(ctx.author,earning)
    await update_bank(member,-1*earning)
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} You robbed {member} and got ֍{earning} ')
  else:
    await ctx.send('hey stupid, you seem stupid cuz u r either robbing urself or a bot')
```

I have added the if function wanting to check whether the mentioned member is not the author and offline and a bot but it doesn't work. The command works even on offline users and bots (it doesn't work on the author, but I want it to not work on any of the three)

###### You can add my bot too to check the feature -  https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=892376302831677520&permissions=8&scope=bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though @idk answer is quite near to it the correct code will be

```py
@client.command(aliases=['rb'])
@commands.cooldown(2, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
async def rob(ctx,member : discord.Member):
  if member == ctx.author or member.status == discord.Status.offline or member.bot:
    await ctx.send('hey stupid, you seem stupid cuz u r either robbing urself or a bot')
    return
  
  await open_account(ctx.author)
  await open_account(member)
  bal = await update_bank(member)
  
  
  if bal[0]<100:
    await ctx.send('It is useless to rob them :(')
    return
  
  earning = random.randrange(0,bal[0])
  
  
  await update_bank(ctx.author,earning)
  await update_bank(member,-1*earning)
  await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} You robbed {member} and got ֍{earning} ')
```

The main thing is that if member(the user to be robbed) is offline, the code won't work, so it protects them. Here we can add bonus for the victim too

Answer (score 0):

try this
i have tested this my self it worked so it should also work for you

```py
@client.command(aliases=['rb'])
@commands.cooldown(2, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
async def rob(ctx,member : discord.Member):
  if member == ctx.author or ctx.author.status == discord.Status.offline or member.bot:
    await ctx.send('hey stupid, you seem stupid cuz u r either robbing urself or a bot')
    return
  
  await open_account(ctx.author)
  await open_account(member)
  bal = await update_bank(member)
  
  
  if bal[0]<100:
    await ctx.send('It is useless to rob them :(')
    return
  
  earning = random.randrange(0,bal[0])
  
  
  await update_bank(ctx.author,earning)
  await update_bank(member,-1*earning)
  await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} You robbed {member} and got ֍{earning} ')
```

Comment: it will be ctx.member.status cuz I want to check that btw thanks